# How does this Python Function evaluate the nth Fibbonacci number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Apparently the following Python function

```
def fib(n):
a, b = 0, 1
while n > 0:              
    a, b, n = b, a+b, n-1 
return b
```

Can return the nth `Fibonacci` number. But how exactly does the `while` loop above work? Can someone walk me through how the code above is able to give `fib(4) = 3`?

Thank you.

Comment: it never will as the code is erroneous. either use `n>1` or return a.

Comment: It is erroneous probably because I didn't indent the block of codes that followed the def command, but these codes work as intended. You can try it yourself.